# Angular 5 Facebook authentication. Trying to redirect to home page

Tags: angular, typescript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am implementing a register with Facebook feature into a Angular 5 application.  I am using Facebook SDK for JavaScript but because of the fact all those methods that allow Facebook authentication are asynchronous I am unable to redirect to my home route URL inside of them.

I would appreciate any help:

This is my code:

I have got a register component which embed a Facebook component like that:

register.component.html:

```
<facebook (successfulFacebookLogin)="onsuccessfulFacebookLogin($event)"></facebook>
```

My Facebook component looks as follows:

```
declare var window: any;
declare var FB: any;
....
export class FacebookComponent implements OnInit {

@Output() successfulFacebookLogin: EventEmitter<boolean> = new 
EventEmitter<boolean>(); //event to pass data to the paretn container

constructor(private _router: Router, private _loginService: LoginService) {

// This function initializes the FB variable 
(function (d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

let thiss=this;
window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
  FB.init({
    appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    autoLogAppEvents: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.10'
  });
  FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };    
}
//Method called when clicking on button Register with Facebook
loginWithFacebook()
{
  //If I enable this line it successfuly redirect to home page  but the 
  //facebook login hasn't happened yet
  //this._router.navigate(['./home']);
  let globalThis = this;
  FB.getLoginStatus((response) => {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {

     FB.api('/me?fields=id, name, first_name,last_name, picture', function (response) {
       console.log(response);
       globalThis._loginService.setFacebookUser(response.first_name, response.last_name, response.id, '', '', response.picture.data.url);
     });
      //this.successfulFacebookLogin.emit(false);
      this._router.navigate(['./home']);
    }
    else {
        FB.login((loginResponse)=>{
          //this.successfulFacebookLogin.emit(false)
          this._router.navigate(['./home']);
        });
    }
   });

 }
}
```

It doesn't redirect to the home page, but something weird happen, both components are loaded, the home and the register component in the same page and the URL changed to /home. The home component is not initialised. It is initialised properly if i redirect before calling FB.getLoginStatus method, as code comment depicts.

Comment: where are you placing the routeroutlet both the components appearing in the same page corresponds to some problem with the outlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel its a `zone` Issue

**Try this**

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(public _router: Router, public _zone: NgZone) {}

this._zone.run(()=>{
   this._router.navigate(['./home']);
});
```

**Update by Gun**

> Angular runs its code in a patched zone where async APIs are patched
>   to notify Angular when async action has happened to rerun change
>   detection.  This makes change detection quite efficient. When code is
>   called that somehow avoids Angular's zone, change detection doesn't
>   kick in.  If a method (even one from an Angular component or similar)
>   is called from code that was invoked outside Angular's zone,
>   everything inside that runs outside the  zone until this event is
>   fully processed. With `zone.run()` we force execution back into
>   Angular's zone

Comment: Hooo man you are right. It worked, Could you give me a  bit more details what the issue is about, please?

Comment: Thank you so much.it's really save my time.